# Upgraded ExpressionEngine, php error on site brings entire site down

Tags: php, php-errors

I've just upgraded from ExpressionEngine 1 to 2. The upgrade ran smoothly and I can access my admin panel. Whenever anyone goes to the site, they're greeted with this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Channel::parse_related_entries() [channel.parse-related-entries]: The script tried >to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the >class definition "DB_Cache" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* >unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition
>
> Filename: channel/mod.channel.php
>
> Line Number: 448
>
> Fatal error: Channel::parse_channel_entries() [entries'>channel.parse-channel-entries]: The script tried to execute a method or access >a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition >"DB_Cache" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* >unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition >in .../system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php on >line 3686

Does anybody have a clue what I need to do to bring my site back online? Help greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I have tried to rebuild a template step-by-step and have identified that the problem is when I close the {exp:channel:entries} tag. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you double checked your file permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that one of add-ons you have is using Channel::parse_related_entries()?

You might want to check that. 
Otherwise it looks like some relationship field did not upgrade correctly.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was a result of reverse related entries not being the correct syntax after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to talk to your hosting provider it looks like you may need a different version of PHP

Comment: Thanks Jez, the system requirements are 5.2.8 or higher, my host is running 5.3. Do you think it requires upgrading to 5.4? The host seem to think it should be okay as it is.

Comment: aaah probably not then - it looks like it is more of a template problem linked to 'related entries'. Maybe you have some relationship fields in your custom fields that didn't upgrade correctly to 2.x?